# QGIS field calculator giving area in acres in layer / project that is in UTM

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, utm

From all the documentation I've been able to find, using `$area` in the field calculator should return the area in the layer's projection's units.  I have a layer in UTM (the project is in the same UTM CRS, which uses meters for its units) but `$area` is giving me acres.  I have double checked this in ArcMap, I used the Calculate Geometry feature, selected acres and arrived at the same value.

It is handy because I was planning on converting to acres myself, but I want to make sure I get consistent results down the road.  I do have acres selected as the unit to be used by QGIS' measure tool.  Does that selection effect the output of `$area` now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since QGIS version 2.14, the '*$area*', '*$length*' and '*$perimeter*' options are calculated based on the unit settings defined under  '**Project > Project Properties**' (see the [changelog](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/#feature-unified-handling-of-distance-and-area-units-and-coordinate-formats) as well as the description in the image below). 
[image]

When you change the units in '**Measure Tool**', it updates the values in '**Project Properties**' and hence you are getting the output in acres. So, if you consistently want the results in a particular unit, you can update that in either **Measure Tool** or **Project Properties**.